# Why is Angular not seeing my controller?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

I am busy following a tutorial, as a total Angular novice, and have reached the point where the Controller is introduced. My MVC view is generating the following markup:

```
<script>
    function PersonController($scope) {
        $scope.persons = [
            { firstName: 'Brady', lastName: 'Kelly' },
            { firstName: 'James', lastName: 'Brown' },
            { firstName: 'Charles', lastName: 'Manson' }
        ];
    }
</script>
<table class="table" data-ng-controller="PersonController">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <span>Last Name</span>
        </th>
        <th>
            <span>First Name</span>
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    <tr data-ng-repeat="pers in persons | orderBy:'lastName'">
        <td>
            {{pers.lastName}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{pers.firstName}}
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When I used the `ng-init` directive to instantiate the person array 'inline', eg:

```
<table class="table" data-ng-init="persons=[....]">
```

the data binding in the table worked, but when I use the `ng-controller` directive, as in my example above, I get an error in Chrome's console stating:

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'PersonController' is not a function, got
>   undefined

Comment: Could you show your full code

Comment: same error here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929296/error-ngareq-argument-myctrl-is-not-a-function-got-undefined

Comment: note that the `angular` controller is something *very* different than the `asp.net MVC` controller.

Comment: look at @sal niro answer, you have missed a call to `angular.module().controller()`

Comment: Thank you, @Martijn, I am quite aware of that difference, and I have no problem with my server side controller.

Comment: You might want to consider removing the asp.net mvc tags then; they have nothing to do with the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to define your controller in a different fashion. I don't see an `app` definition in your example so be sure you have something that looks like the following, then chain your controller off `app`

```
<html ng-app="app">
```

---

```
var app = angular.module('app',
    [
    ]);

app.controller('PersonController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.persons = [
        { firstName: 'Brady', lastName: 'Kelly' },
        { firstName: 'James', lastName: 'Brown' },
        { firstName: 'Charles', lastName: 'Manson' }
    ];
}]);
```

Comment: ng-app must be there somethere, look at the error he got.

Comment: @Werlang you're right, and I thought the same tbh. Probably best to take it out of the answer to target the issue more precisely

Comment: Quite right, @Werlang, I do have an `<html data-ng-app="">`. I'm sure if that was missing, my initial data binding, without controller, would not have worked.

Comment: Thank you @salniro, looks like I needed the `ng-app="app"` where I previously only had `ng-app=""`, then your style of defining the controller vs. just a plain function declaration.

Comment: @ProfK great! I'll roll back my prior edit as well so the answer is complete. You'll definitely want to define your controller in this fashion so you'll have no issues if you eventually minify your scripts

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your angular js module and inject $scope in     PersonController.

```
<script>
        angular.module('app', []);
        function PersonController($scope) {
            $scope.persons = [
                { firstName: 'Brady', lastName: 'Kelly' },
                { firstName: 'James', lastName: 'Brown' },
                { firstName: 'Charles', lastName: 'Manson' }
            ];
        }
        PersonController.$inject = ['$scope'];
    </script>
```